# Difference between jQuery.isPlainObject() and jQuery.isEmptyObject()

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

Can anyone explain what's the difference between jQuery.isPlainObject() and jQuery.isEmptyObject()? They both return true for an object that has no properties. Examples

```
jQuery.isEmptyObject({}); // returns true
jQuery.isPlainObject({}); // returns true
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`$.isEmptyObject()` doesn't consider the object's type, or how it was created; as long as it has totally no properties this function returns true.

`$.isPlainObject()` returns true for objects which are pure `Object` instances; false for objects that are of any other type, e.g. `Number`, `String`, `Function` or a custom type.

---

From the [manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isPlainObject) for `$.isPlainObject()`:

> **Description:** Check to see if an object is a plain object (created using "{}" or "new Object").

So checking an empty object literal `{}` with this function would return true, because that's an instance of the plain `Object` class. And since it's empty, `$.isEmptyObject()` also returns true.

Answer (score 5):

```
jQuery.isEmptyObject()
```

This function will return true if the object is empty (as the name suggests).

```
jQuery.isPlainObject()
```

This function will return true if it is an object literal or (less commonly) the object is created with "`new Object()`".

This example may help:

```
jQuery.isEmptyObject({ 'try' : 'this' }); // returns false
jQuery.isPlainObject({ 'try' : 'this' }); // returns true
```